# Display correct DateTime from db in php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm having a problem with the date time presentation.
I want to display the time of entries into db in a list with title of the entry next to it.
But at the moment, whenever I try to format the time properly, the code only displays one entry instead of all of them.

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
        echo "<li>{$row["date"]}". "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;". $row["title"]. "</li>";
    }
?>
```

like this it obviously just shows whats in the db :

```
2014-09-08 07:09:24.476246       this is it !!
2014-09-05 06:20:20.317560       So nun endlich die Website online
```

but when I format the dates somehow like this ...

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts");

    $new_date = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $date = date_create($new_date[3]);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
        echo "<li>". date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'). "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;". $row["title"]. "</li>";
    }
?>
```

I only get the last row from the db.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php. You see that big red box? If you're writing new PHP code, you should pay attention to what it says. In short, use the `mysqli_` or `PDO` functions instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to format with `date()` directly in loop so no need to `$date` var

```
echo "<li>".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($row["date"]))."&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;". $row["title"]. "</li>";
```

or just make your

```
 $date = date_create($new_date[3]);
```

inside the loop

Also `mysql_*` has been deprecated for more follow @john Conde answer.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `mysql_fetch_row()` outside of your loop you are popping the first record of the recordset off of the stack leaving only the second record. Just create your DateTime() object in your loop.

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
        $date = date_create($row[3]);
        echo "<li>". date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'). "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;". $row["title"]. "</li>";
    }
?>
```

I also do *not* recommend mixing numerical and associative keys when accessing the same data. Stick with one. I recommend associative arrays since they are clearer to the reader what is going on.

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
        $date = date_create($row['date_col']);
        echo "<li>". date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'). "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;". $row["title"]. "</li>";
    }
?>
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).